# Eigen matrix template library over ARM CMSIS-DSP?

Tags: matrix, arm, eigen, cmsis

I need to do a bunch of matrix operations on an MCU (ARM Cortex M). ARM provides a set of basic matrix operations in CMSIS-DSP, in varieties optimized for instruction sets available on different MCUs, but not including some of the advanced operations I need. CMSIS-DSP is great because you can get much better performance on more advanced MCUs without code change (I think). Eigen looks great, but...

I'm wondering if Eigen can be used on top of CMSIS-DSP, by providing wrapper classes for CMSIS-DSP matrices with interfaces required by Eigen.

Has anyone done this? Good or Bad idea?

Related, can Eigen use only static or stack allocation (no heap) and ideally no exceptions?

Alternatively, is there another matrix library more suited to MCUs? Simunova seems to have disappeared though there's a copy of MTL4 on Github. Any pointers appreciated!